# how can i copy my dll to deploy my website?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am having trouble finding the devxpress dll on my project. they said to set the copy local property of they dll to true but i can't seem to find my dll i can add references with ease but there is no dll on my project solution the bin folder only has App_License.dll can anyone please give me and answer and a brief explanation?

Answer (score 1):

It's the reference that you have to set copy local property to true. Find the reference under references in your project, right click, properties, and then one should be copy local. Set that to true.

Comment: sorry I'm new at this. my solution explorer doesn't have a reference folder

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261349/how-do-i-show-the-references-folder-in-solution-explorer-without-selecting-show. You have to set show all files if it is a vb project.

Comment: excuse me sorry but it's a website and not a web application.

Comment: Still should be the same procedure I believe