# How to use TFS Build in the best way

Tags: dll, tfs, tfsbuild, versioning

We have a developer team and there are many projects/solutions. So there are some projects which are used in some solutions.

For example project X is used in Solution A, Solution B and Solution C..

Our team have added the project as a reference instead of dll. So if somebody has change the code and commit to TFS and another developer pull the repository, so project X has been changed and the developer has to make combile the new project X for his solution because the project X was added as a reference.

So, i know that its better to add the dll file of project X and other solutions will not be effected by project X changes.

However, we have just started to use TFS build and i think that something going wrong. We have a Relase folder that contains only buildt DLLS in TFS server and the project has reference from these DLL. But in local machine, our team uses dlls which are build of project X instead of adding directly Project X as reference. But still if project X has been changed and compiled then the build DLL will be changed and the solution has to be reviewed again.

I know its a bit complicated but my question is that How we can add reference as DLL for all team (with versioning). For example all developer's computer has C:\Development\Relases folder and we can add Folders like

Project X 1.1 
Project X 1.2

and the developers directly reference dll from this folder considering versions. But for example if another developer made a new version of Project X 1.3, i want to see also new dll on C:\Development\Relases folder.

How it can be possible and is it a good solution? If not what is your advice?

PS: We have VS Ent. 20015 and Microsoft Visual Studio TFS 14.102.25423.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the solution will using the latest dll buildt by project X. You may could check in the dll in TFS as source control. Even though source control dll is not a recommend way, but this maybe the best practices to meet your situation.

Then you just need to manage the dll the same as other external dll. Detail ways you can refer the answer from *Will* in this question: [TFS dll and references issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18238745/tfs-dll-and-references-issues)

Comment: I found out the solution. We are going to use Nuget :) we are creating our nuget package in our server and everything seems easier. Thanx for reply

Comment: exactly :) and if you have any idea about my new question, please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163483/how-to-automatically-create-and-push-nuget-package-after-building