# How to automatically create and push Nuget Package after building

Tags: nuget-package

We want to create nuget packages for our all products (dll) but there are several developers and want to find out the easiest way to do that.

It is possible to use console manager to do that but I am looking for a general solution. Because the projects can have dependencies or files and also the important thing is versioning. So I am looking for a tool which can create a package and push for us considering dependencies, versioning etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using TFS Build that has Nuget packager and publisher..